# Imagemagik and php imagecopy doesn't preserve transparency

Tags: php, image, gd

Im facing a strange problem when i use imagemagik converted image with php imagecopy.. Here is my code

```
$cmd = "convert ".realpath($temp1)." -alpha set -channel alpha -background none -vignette 0x3 ".$dest_img;
exec($cmd);
```

This code makes the edges feathered so i can have a clean merging.. Here is my code for merging image

```
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($postcard_img);
    $frame = imagecreatefrompng($thumb_img);

    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($postcard_img);
    imagealphablending($frame,true);

    //imagecopymerge($image, $frame, $coords[0], $coords[1], 0, 0, $w, $h, 100);
    imagecopy($image, $frame, $coords[0], $coords[1], 0, 0, $w, $h);
```

And here is the result

[image]

Okay now the strange stuff.. IF I don't use ImageMagik and simply merge it by replacing imagecopy() with imagecopymerge() it works then but leaves rough edges.. Here is the code of imagecopymerge()

```
    $postcard_img = $postcard[0]["ms_filepath"].$postcard[0]["ms_filename"];
    $thumb_img = $thumb[0]["ms_thumbpath"].$thumb[0]["ms_thumbname"];

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($postcard_img);
    $frame = imagecreatefrompng($thumb_img);

    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($postcard_img);
    imagealphablending($frame,true);

    imagecopymerge($image, $frame, $coords[0], $coords[1], 0, 0, $w, $h, 100);
```

And here is the result (See the rough edges)

[image]

All i need is the feathered image.. Any idea why its happening and how to overcome it?

Comment: Why don't you use Imagemagick for everything?

Comment: yeah im thinking of going your way but isn't there any way other than imagemagik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Resistance is futile.

```
convert ( frame.png -channel alpha -blur 0x5 -level 50%,100% ) ( avatar.jpg -geometry +70+120 ) -compose dstover -composite output.png
```

[image]

You can always make frame with feathered edges in Photoshop (or similar) and just put one on top of another.

Comment: Its an online application so can't use photoshop :)

Comment: @abdulwahabkotwal I meant just to create frame, but nevermind, you can do what you want with imagemagick, command line photoshop ;)